# Why Balmer series exist?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I was reading about Bohr's atomic model in our textbook when came up with this question:
Since the electron in hydrogen atom is most stable in the first orbit, why should it descend from higher orbits to any orbit except the first orbit(that means balmer series for example)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emission_spectrum and this one too http://www.avogadro.co.uk/light/bohr/spectra.htm

Comment: It says "This is as a result of an electron 'falling' from a higher energy level to one of lower energy." What I want to know is why"a lower energy level" and not the ground state as it is the most stable?

Comment: @Shadock The references cited here are more relevant http://www.ioffe.ru/astro/QC/CMBR/sp_tr.html Transition to the lowest energy is most probable, but others have a non-zero probability.  I think QED is needed to explain properly.

Comment: I see...; thanks, the tables are although well clarifying.

Comment: @DavePhD thank you for the link. What means QED?

Comment: @Shadock quantum electrodynamics

Comment: @orthocresol DavePhD ask him before if he knows that. If it is too complicated for the person who ask the question he will never accept your answer...

Comment: I think a less sophisticated explanation might suffice. Yes, sometimes an electron would fall to an intermediate state and remain there for a few long microseconds before falling further to the ground state; so what? Who said that all things must go straight to the ground state? If that were the case, all organic life (including us) would die and decompose instantly.

Comment: Depending on the higher energy wave function quantum numbers, decay directly to the ground state may not be allowable (at least in the dipole approximation).

Comment: @IvanNeretin maybe without QED like this http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node119.html#e3.115 ?

Comment: or with qed https://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Courses/NanoOptics/app_b.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire process has two parts: Excitation and relaxation. The first is clear enough, we excite an electron into a higher energy level.

Now this electron wants to fall back down. There is no roadsign or intrinsic selection rule that requires the electron to immediately go back to the ground state. *Any* state in a lower shell will be less energetic and by chance electron 1 happens to stop in state A while electron 2 of a different atoms stops in state B. Any electron that is not in a ground state will remain there — probably for a duration of about a few femtoseconds or less — and then relax further. The universe is not deterministic so nothing is telling the electron it has to take the fastest path.

Note that this gedankenexperiment does not make any prediction which path is most *likely*. You would need more theory (that DavePhD is likely to give) to explain that.

Comment: Well, for example if the H atom is in the 3s or any other s state, it will  need to go to an intermediate state before going to the ground state, for electric dipole radiation.  The 2s lifetime is therefore infinite for electric dipole radiation.  Generally, the other lifetimes are in the nanoseconds. http://www.physik.uni-wuerzburg.de/EP4/teaching/WS2012_13/KM_ueb/PhysRev.148.1.pdf